# ASP.NET Chart Plotting points with value of 0

Tags: asp.net, charts, plot

I was wondering if anyone knows if ASP.NET charts plot points when you specify the value of 0, assuming that every other point is above the value of 0.  So lets say for example, we have values: `{0, 0, 0, 4234, 4342, 6354, 75656 0, 0, 0, 56342, 2243, 3432, 0, 0, 0}`  Will asp.net plot any of the 0's or will it simply skip them and show the next dates because it will consider there was no data for those 0's.

For sake of argument lets say we are using a column graph that plots number of eggs laid by all chickens in Canada for range of days.

So will my graph show empty columns for the 0's or will it condense and show the next column with data instead.

Comment: From My Experience ASP will plot the 0's

Comment: @Kevin Kunderman Yes you are right, I realized the mistake in my code which was preventing that result.  If you would like, post an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From My Experience ASP will plot the 0's